# Are there any historical Bibles entirely written on parchment?

Tags: history, tanach, torah-writing

Mishneh Torah, Tefillin, Mezuzah and the Torah Scroll 7:15:

> מותר לדבק תורה נביאים וכתובים בכרך אחד .
>
> It is permissible to attach Torah, Prophets and Writings in one
>   scroll.

Between the end of Devarim and the beginning of Yehoshua, one needs 4 lines of separation, similar to how each of book of the Chumash is separated from the next one.

If Ramba"m mentions this, I assume that someone, at that time, must have done this. Or was Ramba"m just mentioning this as allowable, yet no one ever did it? Is there any evidence that someone at some time did this?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60000/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bava Batra 13b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=13b&format=pdf):

> אמר רבי מעשה והביאו לפנינו תורה נביאים וכתובים מדובקים כאחד והכשרנום
>
> Rebbi said: one time they brought before us Torah, Neviim and Ketuvim stuck together like one and we declared it Kosher.