# Are there any extant scrolls containing multiple books of Nach?

Tags: jewish-books, sefer-torah, safrus

Related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/are-there-any-historical-bibles-entirely-written-on-parchment), are there any known extant scrolls containing either all of tanach or multiple books of Na"ch? I am not counting trei-asar scrolls as they are considered one Book for purposes of the official count.

Comment: All of Tanach on a single scroll, or all of Tanach spread across multiple scrolls but as part of a set?

Comment: Based on linked question, appears you're asking about a single scroll.  It is unlikely any of those exist(ed).

Comment: I have seen 2 books of Neviim on the same Klaf. I have also seen all five Megillot on the same Klaf.

Comment: @DoubleAA, sounds like an answer.

Comment: Perhaps a visit to the Israel Museum might help. If there's anywhere they'd be publicly available for viewing, it'd be there. If you aren't already in Israel... well, start booking a flight!

Comment: @DoubleAA That does sound like an answer. Come to think of it, I've seen all 5 megillos on one scroll as well but never multiple neviim.