# Can multiple books of Prophets be written on a single parchment?

Tags: halacha, navi-prophets, safrus

My niece who lives in Ramat Bet Shemesh told me that her shul reads all haftarot from a klaf (parchment).

It has been a while since I have seen a shul use a scroll for haftarah. The last shul I attended had separate scrolls for each book of the prophets.

I [know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38446/759) that Ramba"m in Hilchot Sifrei Torah 7:14 states that one may write the **entire Tanac"h** in a single scroll and that this has been done before.

Can one write more than one book of "Nevi'im* on a single scroll? Or is Rambam's statement applicable to only all of tanac"h but not just a part of it?

Comment: Why would you think it's an all or nothing sort of situation?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.dafyomi.co.il/lectures/marei-shab115.pdf . There seems to be a collection of quotes around the subject.